# IDEA cannot find the package org.apache.kafka.common.message in kafka 2.4 source code

Tags: apache-kafka

I try to use IDEA to read kafka 2.4 source code downloaded from github. But I find the whole org.apache.kafka.common.message package is missing. 
What went wrong?

[image]

Comment: What are you doing that needs the request/response classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are generated classes, in order to have them you will need to build the Kafka project with Gradle, in short, you'll need to do: `./gradlew jar` and wait for the project to build. In IntelliJ by default they will end up under `kafka/clients/src/generated[main]/java/org/apache/kafka/common/message`

You can get instructions on how to do it on the Kafka [Developer Setup](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Developer+Setup) page

You can find instructions on how to [install Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html) on their official page.